# Use pandas to_datetime without removing time information

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

With this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["2013-03-13T00:00:00"], columns=["t"])
pd.to_datetime(dft["t"])
```

The result is:

```
0   2013-03-13
Name: t, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But I want to keep the time information, altought 00:00:00, because there are other rows with more relevant time information. Anyway, pandas is removing it when doing `to_datetime`. I've tried different arguments to `to_datetime` without success.

```py
pd.__version__
'1.5.3'

sys.version
'3.10.9 (main, Feb 28 2023, 09:28:42) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]'
```

Comment: Dont worry, it not remove, only not display if all displayed datetimes has `00:00:00` times, test `pd.to_datetime(dft["t"]).tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont worry, it not remove, only not display if all displayed datetimes has `00:00:00` times:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(["2013-03-13T00:00:00"] * 3 + ['2013-03-13T10:00:00'] * 2, columns=["t"])
d = pd.to_datetime(dft["t"])
print (d)
0   2013-03-13 00:00:00
1   2013-03-13 00:00:00
2   2013-03-13 00:00:00
3   2013-03-13 10:00:00
4   2013-03-13 10:00:00
Name: t, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (d.head(3))
0   2013-03-13
1   2013-03-13
2   2013-03-13
Name: t, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (d.tolist())
[Timestamp('2013-03-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-03-13 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2013-03-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-03-13 10:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2013-03-13 10:00:00')]
```

Comment: true, thanks. That a poor default behaviour IMHO, specially if you export to .csv and loss time information.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.to_datetime(df["t"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```